# BAT Close Program if another is running

Tags: batch-file, task

I wanted a BAT program that I can use with Task Scheduler so if I open "java.exe", it will close itself. Is this possible?

Thanks!

Comment: This is definitely possible. What have you tried so far?

Comment: I'm pretty new to .bat files.
I just know how to change colors, open programs, ipconfig, and stuff that level.

Comment: I'm not going to write the code for you, but I'll point you in the right direction. You can use `tasklist` to get a list of currently running tasks, and you can use `find` to search a chunk of text for a specific string. You can use `|` to use the output of one command as the input of another command. You can use `exit` to end the script that is currently running.

Answer (score 1):

Since `findstr` returns 0 if a string exists in the input, and non-zero otherwise, you can test on the `ERRORLEVEL` of that command to know whether a program is running or not.

```
tasklist | findstr /i "java.exe" > NUL
if ERRORLEVEL 1 exit /b 1
echo ...do something here ...
```

You can compact this in to a single line with the `||` boolean operator.

```
tasklist | findstr /i "java.exe" >NUL || exit /b 1
echo ...do something here ...
```

Run `help findstr` to see a list of options you can give.  If you want more precise matches such that "java.exe" does not match "notjava.exe", you can use the `/B` switch.

```
tasklist | findstr /i /b "java.exe" >NUL || exit /b 1
echo ... do something here ...
```

The `tasklist` program can do its own filtering, but then you still have to run the output through `findstr` because for some reason `tasklist` always  seems to set `ERRORLEVEL` to 0.  The output probably changes depending on the computer's localization settings, too, so it's not as flexible and generic of a solution.  But here it is:

```
tasklist /fi "imagename eq iexplore.exe" | findstr "iexplore.exe" >NUL && echo the task is running
```

If you want your batch file to stop another process that is running, first you'd do one of the above options to see whether it is running, and then you'd run `taskkill` to stop it.  E.g.,

```
taskkill /im /t "java.exe"
```

See `taskkill /?` for more options.  Depending on your use case, you might just go directly to `taskkill` with its filter options, like this:

```
taskkill /fi "imagename eq java.exe"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this batch like this :

```
@echo off
Set Process2Kill=java
FOR /F "usebackq tokens=2" %%i IN (`tasklist ^| findstr /r /b "%Process2Kill%*[.]exe"`) DO taskkill /pid %%i
pause
```

- The command_to_process needs back quotes (**``**) on both sides of the
  command.
- Pipes ("**|**") inside of the command_to_process need to be escaped with
  a caret ("**^**").
- [FOR /F documentation](http://ss64.com/nt/for_cmd.html)
- [Findstr documentation](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490907.aspx)